# Match variable length path while limiting node type

Tags: cypher

Let's say I have a graph where the nodes are either Red or Green.  I'm starting at a Red node and I would like to get all the other red nodes that are connected to my starting node, going only through Green nodes.

For instance, if I have the following graph:

```
   (R1)
  /    \
(G1)   (G3)
 |      |
(G2)   (R3)
 |      |
(G5)   (G4)
 |      |
(R2)   (R4)
```

I would like to get the following result set:

```
R1, R2
R1, R3
```

Any ideas on how to write that query?

Thanks,

EDIT:
To create the graph:

```
CREATE (r1:Red{label: "R1"})-[:foo]->(g1:Green{label: "G1"})-[:foo]->(g2:Green{label: "G2"})-[:foo]->(g5:Green{label:"G5"})-[:foo]->(r2:Red{label: "R2"}),
    (r1)-[:foo]->(g3:Green{label: "G3"})-[:foo]->(r3:Red{label: "R3"})-[:foo]->(g4:Green{label: "G4"})-[:foo]->(r4:Red{label: "R4"});
```

I've tried the following query but it gives me back node R4, which I don't want.

```
 MATCH (r1:Red{label:'R1'})-[:foo*]->(green:Green)-->(other_red) RETURN r1, green, other_red
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
MATCH p = (r1:Red {label:'R1'})-[:foo*]->(green:Green)-[:foo]->(other_red:Red) 
WITH r1, green, other_red, [n IN nodes(p) WHERE 'Red' in labels(n) | n] as redNodes
WHERE length(redNodes) = 2
RETURN r1, green, other_red
```

It makes sure that only the first red node is taken by keeping the paths that contain only 2 red nodes (`r1` and `other_red`).

Answer (score 0):

Your data setup:

```
CREATE (r1 {label: "R1"})-[:foo]->(g1 {label: "G1"})-[:foo]->(g2 {label: "G2"})-[:foo]->(r2 {label: "R2"}),
       (r1)-[:foo]->(g3 {label: "G3"})-[:foo]->(r3 {label: "R3"})-[:foo]->(g4 {label: "G4"})-[:foo]->(r4 {label: "R4"});
```

Now here's your query:

```
MATCH (r1 { label: "R1"})-[:foo*1..3]->(target)
WHERE target.label =~ "R.*"
RETURN r1.label, target.label;
```

This query uses a variable length path (`[:foo*1.3]`) which specifies that the path must be at least one step long, no longer than 3 steps.  Then, I filter based on nodes with a label that starts with "R".  This gives the right result, otherwise G1, G2, and G3 would also be in the result set, because they're within that number of hops.

Comment: Is there any way to constrain the intermediate nodes of the path and not limit it's length?  There are situations where another red node is connected by more than just 3 green nodes and increasing the length of the path in your case would capture unwanted Reds.

Comment: You can remove the length limitation by making it `[:foo*1..]`.  And by using `WHERE` clauses, you can further constrain the intermediate nodes.  What constraints do you want?   So yes, you can do both of these...the answer is addressing what you provided in the question.

Comment: If I remove the length constraint, the node R4 will be returned, which I don't want.  I updated my example to be more representative.  To reiterate, I would like to start at a node and traverse outgoing relations through Green nodes until the first Red node is encountered.